# Изменение типа Input при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на кнопку URL `type="file"` менялся на `type="text"`?

Html:

```
<form action="#" method="#" class="upload-form">
     <input type="file" name="upload-image">
     <a href="#">URL</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Ну и меняете тип с помощью метода attr()

    $('[type="file"]').on('click', function(){
        $(this).attr('type', 'text');
    });

Answer (score 2):

Пробуйте так:
HTML

```
<input type='text' id='input'> </input>
```

JS

```
    $('#input').click(function() {
    var b = $(this).attr('type','file');
})
```

Всё, при клике на input, все должно сработать, удачи-c.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.upload-form').find('input[type=file]').on('click', function(){
  this.type = 'text';
});
```

Comment: Возможно, нужно `click` поменять на `change`, который сработает после выбора файла на диске.